# Jquery submit() take Priority over form onSubmit

Tags: jquery, forms, submission

I have a form:

```
<form onsubmit="return doSomethingCrazy();">
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

And I have some js:

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
    err = 0;

    $(this).find('.formInteger').each(function(){
        var val = $(this).val();

        if (val != '' && parseInt(val) != val)
        {
            err++;
            $(this).addClass('invalid');
        }
    });

    if (err > 0)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```

I want the jquery to fire and prevent the onsubmit from occurring if err > 0.  In all my testing, it seems to be firing the onsubmit on the form before the jquery and my code never gets to run.

I am adding this to a large site and I am trying to do this without having to touch every form.  I can get this to work from the submit button being clicked, but that doesn't rule out people hitting enter in a text field (nor do I want to remove the ability to hit enter in a text field).  Any thoughts as to how I can accomplish this?

Comment: why not just remove the onSubmit and put `doSomethingCrazy` into the submit handler?

Comment: Do you want the `onsubmit` handler to execute at all?

Comment: It is just a random name I put in.  This form validation will be run on probably 100+ different forms across the site, and each form may (or may not) have an onsubmit as part of the form.  Most of the onsubmits are $.ajax calls to submit the form data.

Comment: The onsubmit handler should fire if validation passes.

Comment: I changed it to  $('input[type="submit"]').click(function(e){ and it works even if the enter key is pressed.